# What is the most efficient way to store a tree data structure in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tree

I was thinking the simplest thing would be a flat list:

```
{
  id: ObjectId()
  parentId:  ObjectId()
  value: ‘foo’,
}
```

Just one big collection. To find the child nodes of a node, just search through the list and find all instances where the parentId equals the current node id. *Indexes on id/parentId.*

This might be faster for writes, but reads might become pretty horrific.
And we will have a lot more reads than writes!

MongoDB has some sort of built in tree data structure:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

But I am wondering how that differs from a flat list like the one I proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define an index on `id` and an index on `parentId`, find the children of a node should be really fast.

Why do you think it'll be horrific?

---

**UPDATE:** The worst case scenario would be `O(log N)` but it's important to note that the bucket size Mongo uses is 8192 ([source](https://github.com/datacratic/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongo/db/btree.h)). That means there's a really small constant multiplying this time which means MongoDB operations can be quite fast.

Comment: It wouldn't be that bad. But everytime you needed to find the the children of a node you'd have to look at the same collection and re-read it. Worst case I think is log(n) time to read whole thing with an index on it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills yes, but they're really fast because of the size of the tree buckets. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky in real-world apps. MongoDB recommends five ways:

> Model Tree Structures with Parent References:
> Presents a data model that organizes documents in a tree-like structure by storing references to "parent" nodes in "child" nodes.

> Model Tree Structures with Child References:
> Presents a data model that organizes documents in a tree-like structure by storing references to "child" nodes in "parent" nodes.

> Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors:
> Presents a data model that organizes documents in a tree-like structure by storing references to "parent" nodes and an array that stores all ancestors.

> Model Tree Structures with Materialized Paths:
> Presents a data model that organizes documents in a tree-like structure by storing full relationship paths between documents. In addition to the tree node, each document stores the _id of the node's ancestors or path as a string.

> Model Tree Structures with Nested Sets:
> Presents a data model that organizes documents in a tree-like structure using the Nested Sets pattern. This optimizes discovering subtrees at the expense of tree mutability.

Find full explanation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/).